# Form data doesn't be passed to view in Django

Tags: python, django

I am having trouble to see the post data in template in Django.

The error message from Django is:

**"CSRF verification failed. Request aborted."**

Here is my code:

**submitted form:**

```
<form action="/submitted/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    *.... User input some data ....*
</form>
```

**result page (test.html):**

```
<body>
    {{ passed_dict }}
</body>
```

**view.py**

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.template import RequestContext

def submitted(request):
    passed_dict = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        passed_dict.update(csrf(request))
        ''' get the data from post and do things '''
    else:
        passed_dict['result'] = 'this_is_result'

    ## no matter what thing did, back to the original page.
    return render(request, 'group_detail.html', passed_dict)
```

I follow the setting guide on the Django site, but still doesn't work.

Did I miss something ?

Comment: can u `print passed_dict`  after `passed_dict.update(csrf(request))` . what u see ?

Comment: "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted."

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass back the context, something like. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext)

```
 return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                          passed_dict,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: The reason is "CSRF token missing or incorrect.", I think the request didn't be sent successfully.

Comment: you will have to pass the context as well, if you check the working of template and render,
>>> from django.template import Context, Template
>>> t = Template("My name is {{ person.first_name }}.")
>>> d = {"person": {"first_name": "Joe", "last_name": "Johnson"}}
>>> t.render(Context(d))

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: ok, can you comment this passed_dict.update(csrf(request)) and run it again and see ?

Answer (score 0):

No need to see the POST data. The issue is clear: you are not passing the CSRF token in the view that generates the form in the first place. If it's not in the generated form, it won't be in the POST data.

The usual pattern in Django is to use the same view to generate the form and to process the POST, but you seem to have split them up. You need to be passing the token in both views. Note the usual way to do this is to use a RequestContext (or the `render` shortcut), rather than adding it manually to the context.

**Edit** OK, so for the third time, the problem is in the step that renders the form on GET - where *you are not passing the CSRF token*. Again, as I said above, you should not be adding it manually at all, but using the `render` shortcut to ensure that context processors are run: `render(request, 'group_detail.html', passed_dict)`.

Comment: To use the usual pattern in Django. I set the `action=""` in my form, and write down `if request.method == 'POST'` in my view that generate form. But it still doesn't work. Does use the Django's Form necessary ? Or I can use the normal way to generate form ?

Comment: As I said, the problem is not with the POST step. Please show the full view (edit your question).

Comment: Seriously, I'm not going to be able to help you until you post the actual real view. Where is CSRF supposed to be coming from in that code? Is it in `passed_dict`? How can I tell? Post the full code.

Comment: It's almost the full code, the remaining codes are just call other module/class. I am not sure if it is clear.

Comment: another error that is `d doesn't look like a module path`, and it's caused in `module_loading.py` when generating the form page.